# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ErrorHandler in ms access connectivity with java8

Tags: java

I am trying to connect Ms Access database with java 8 version. But as in this version jdbcodbcbridge driver has been removed, so following jar files need to be included :

```
**ucanaccess-x.x.x.jar
HSQLDB (hsqldb.jar, version 2.2.5 or newer)
,Jackcess (jackcess-2.x.x.jar)
,commons-lang (commons-lang-2.6.jar, or newer 2.x version)
,commons-logging (commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, or newer 1.x version)**
```

I have bought all these jar files in my eclipse through Build Path option.

But still when i am executing the following code it is coming up with **error** as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   **com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ErrorHandler**    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   demo.JDBCDemo.main(JDBCDemo.java:11) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ErrorHandler    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 3 more

And my code is:

```
    import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ErrorHandler;
public class JDBCDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\isha\\Desktop\\StudentData.accdb");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    String str="insert into NameData values(4,'ram')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(str);
    String s="select * from NameData";
    ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery(s);
    while(res.next()){
    System.out.println(res.getString(1)+":"+res.getString(2));
    Enumeration e=DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while(e.hasMoreElements()){
        Driver d=(Driver)e.nextElement();
        System.out.println(d.getClass().getName());
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ErrorHandler; this line was added by me to just check the class presence.

Comment: Maybe the jars are not part of the classpath

Comment: i am doing my programming in eclipse. So in its case we bring the jar files via bulid path in the project and that i did

Comment: And where you run your Project* also in eclipse?

Comment: clean and rebuild your code.

Comment: It may help to make it work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an old obsolete version of jackcess in your classpath. Please add to your classpath ucanaccess.jar the  jars in the folder lib of the specific ucanaccess distribution you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="insert into NameData values(4,'ram')";
```

in which columns you insert this values?

Comment: I have table in ms access of name NameData in StudentData.accdb with columns ID and Name

Comment: Shouldn't then be `INSERT INTO NameData (ID,Name) VALUES (4, 'ram')` ?